# Asp.net Obout grid, how can i post data without page refresh, using its built in function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview, obout

i am using this obout grid in asp, how can i use ajax to filter this grid

I mean i would have these fields above the grid

Name [......]       Date From [......] Date To[.......]
Year [......]

SUBMIT BUTTON

Now i dont want page refreshing, to filter it,
If i click on submit button, the grid should refresh and filter according to critera, does obout provide any such functionality to use its component with jquery or ajax?

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with AJAX.

You have to put your gridview in an update panel and add an Asynchronous post back trigger to your Click button. Like...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnl" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildTrigger="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Gridview></asp:Gridview>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You solved my issue, thanks Muhammad, can i increase your rate on this site, is there anyway?

Comment: Along with other answers yours was very helpful. Thanks.